# How do I suppress the jt400 already in the list?

Tags: java, db2, ibm-watson

I am getting so many warning regarding `jt400.jar` in dev and test environment. Everything working fine, but these warning message is bothering, not able to get the same warning in local. We are trying to connect to DB2 and read the data, we can read the data, but we have below warning. In order to be in production, we need to remove these warning.

It looks like we have this problem in ibm developer books. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=16194dc5-5a43-4a13-afc8-29229f5f6618

```
java.sql.SQLWarning: [PWS0082] 1 library(s) not added to the library list.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.getSQLWarning(JDError.java:362) ~[jt400.jar:JTOpen 9.3]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDLibraryList.addOnServer(JDLibraryList.java:328) ~[jt400.jar:JTOpen 9.3]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:3622) ~[jt400.jar:JTOpen 9.3]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:3421) ~[jt400.jar:JTOpen 9.3]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:3414) ~[jt400.jar:JTOpen 9.3]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.prepareConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1419) ~[jt400.jar:JTOpen 9.3]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.initializeConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1256) ~[jt400.jar:JTOpen 9.3]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.connect(AS400JDBCDriver.java:395) ~[jt400.jar:JTOpen 9.3]
```

How do I suppress the warning ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1 library(s) not added to the library list

In your JDBC connection string, you've specified a library name that doesn't exist on the machine you're connecting to..

Look at what you're using for the `libraries` property.  Remove the library that doesn't exist.

Comment: without removing it, can we just suppress using java annotation?